# Can I use keyframes and the nla editor at the same time?

Tags: animation, nla-editor

I'm animating a scene with keyframes in the dope sheet. I have imported a walk cycle for a character in the form of an action. I'm not sure how to add the walk cycle in a part of the scene because it gets rid of all the keyframes I've done so far.

It's like I can only have keyframes OR actions in the NLA but not both. I'm sure that's gotta be a 'me' problem, so can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong? This is my first venture into the NLA so I'm not entirely sure whats going on. I understand the concept, but I want to keep the keyframes that's come before and just add the walk cycle to the character.

Thank you

Comment: Hello, please give more details, show some screenshots, maybe share your file, are the actions supposed to follow or combine? etc...